# What happened to my n00b question?

Tags: support

Moderators: I had a n00b question [here](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/940/is-anyone-who-uses-a-strawman-argument-lying), some feedback and negative points were given and post was deleted.

I'm not an admin so I don't know what was said on this deleted post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to see your own, deleted posts. This question was closed and later deleted because questions about skepticism itself, like yours, are off-topic here. Your question was also very subjective, we generally require questions that have an objective answer, this is a Q&A site and it is not meant for extended discussions.

There was a comment on the question explaining this, and you should still be able to see it even when the question is deleted.

Comment: I can confirm that I get 404 page not found when signing in and clicking on that above link.  I'm using the same account I used when creating the post.  Perhaps since I did not delete the post is why I can't read it.

Comment: @maker This should not happen, you should be able to view your own questions even if they're deleted by a moderator. I don't know why it doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Let me know if you need me for more troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

The comment said:

> Welcome to Skeptics.SE, makerofthings7! This question is not on topic, as defined in the FAQ. Skeptics.SE is about applied skepticism, not the philosophical aspect of it.